# How to add legend text into legend symbol

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a follow-up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816484/how-to-position-labels-correctly-in-a-grouped-beeswarm-plot).

Consider this modified example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(am), y = mpg, color = factor(am))) +
  geom_point(shape = 15, size = 6, alpha = 0.7,
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, height = 0, seed = 31)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = am), 
            position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, height = 0, seed = 31), 
            size = 3, color = "black")
```

[image]

How can I put the `0` and `1` in the legend into the the squares?
I would expect this:
[image]

The closest solution I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72659429/add-text-to-legend-symbols-in-ggplot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting my answer from the referenced post to your case you could achieve your desired result like so:

Note: Basically this requires replacing `draw_key_rect` by `draw_key_point`, using `color` instead of `fill`, adapting the `key_label` data frame and using a different color palette. Also, I dropped the code for adjusting the key width which at least for your example data is not required. Finally I dropped the legend text via `theme` options.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

# Color palette
pal <- scales::hue_pal()(2)
names(pal) <- c("0", "1")

# Legend key labels
key_label <- mtcars |>
  distinct(am) |>
  mutate(key_label = am) |>
  tibble::deframe()

# Custom key glyph
draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  data_text <- data
  data_text$label <- key_label[names(pal)[match(data$colour, pal)]]
  data_text[c("fill", "shape", "stroke")] <- NULL
  data_text$colour <- "black"
  data_text$size <- 11 / .pt

  grid::grobTree(
    draw_key_point(data, list()),
    draw_key_text(data_text, list())
  )
}

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(am), y = mpg, color = factor(am))) +
  geom_point(
    shape = 15, size = 6, alpha = 0.7,
    position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, height = 0, seed = 31),
    key_glyph = "cust"
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = am),
    position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, height = 0, seed = 31),
    size = 3, color = "black"
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.text = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: You are perfect! Now I understand!